# How import Pydev project into interactive console?

Tags: python, pydev

Newbie question (I'm just getting started with Python and Pydev):

I've created a project "Playground" with (standard?) src/root sub-folder. In there I've created example.py.

How do I import my "example" module into Pydev's interactive console?
">>> import example" gives: "ImportError: No module named example"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer on the Plone website: [Setting up PYTHONPATH in Eclipse project](http://plone.org/documentation/tutorial/developing-plone-with-eclipse/setting-up-pythonpath-in-eclipse). 
This provides a convenient way to set PYTHONPATH on a per project basis. In my case I added "/Playground/src/root" to the Source Folders list. ">>> import example" then worked. (I'm still surprised project files aren't imported by default, though.)

Thank you jldupont for pointing me in the right direction (re. PYTHONPATH)!

Answer (score 5):

You need to set your PYTHONPATH accordingly (Google search is your friend) or use *.pth in your installation *site-packages* directory pointing to your project path.  Don't forget to set your interpreter details with Pydev (Window->Preferences->Pydev->interpreter).

Comment: So, just to be clear, Pydev doesn't do anything automatic to help me call me project code from its interactive console? I have to append to the PYTHONPATH environment variable for every new Pydev project I start?

If so, maybe I'm asking the wrong question. What's the most convenient way to call a method of a project module when using Pydev?

Comment: I can't be sure 100% because I have given up some time ago in using the integrated console: I'd rather use a separate system console to make sure things are *really* correct ;-) In any case, I was introduced to a nice way to setup my Python/Eclipse dev environment recently which might interest you (instead of waiting for Pydev to catch up): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522867/python-how-do-you-setup-your-workspace-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Following the PYTHONPATH advice above, I used a bit of a hack to get this working. If I understand your question, you want to have the current working directory in the IPython environment set to the directory in which your active file resides. So if you are editing D:/projects/file.py, you want the pwd() command (in IPython) to return D:/projects. This is where the hacked together part of my solution comes from. All my projects are on my D drive, but all the normal python imports come from the install location on my C drive. So the following:

```
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
```

results in a list on which only one path is on the D drive, and that path (from the answers above) is of my active file's directory. If you don't use the D drive, then there should be some other unique way of identifying which of the paths in that list pertains to your projects. If there isn't a way of uniquely identifying your project path, then this answer doesn't work. But in the simple case of "D:/" being enough of a unique identifier, this is my startup code in the settings (Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interactive Console)

```
import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))
import os;os.chdir([p for p in os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep) if p.startswith("D")][0])
pwd()
```